# How to disable older GCM token after app update?

Tags: android, ios, push, android-update-app

I upgrade notification module from GCM to FCM and release to 'Appstore' and 'playstore'.
Issue is that updated App from old version device is receiving duplicated message. But delete app and reinstall it's ok just receive one message.

> I found reason is older gcm token is still activated even app updated.
>   one app has two activated token(one is gcm,another is fcm)

### older gcm token

> d3-b3LP9_mU:APA91bHMJkNZwJdt8R1beKy5B4T....

### newer fcm token

> d3-b3LP9_mU:APA91bEDC5Y4gqp3V9xyU.......

How can i disable older gcm token???

Comment: I cannot find disable older gcm token. so i was find tokens like 'd3-b3LP9_mU%' in db and change it manually